# Copying .env files To Mutliple Host Machines w/ Pm2

Tags: javascript, deployment, environment-variables, pm2, production

I'm trying to deploy my Node.js script to multiple hosts using Pm2's deploy process.

It's working fine using a single host, with the following `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: `./envs/.production.env` });
  const path = require("path");

  module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: process.env.APP_NAME,
        interpreter: process.env.NODE_PATH,
        cwd: process.env.PROJECT_PATH
        script: "dist/index.js",
        instances: process.env.INSTANCES || 0,
        exec_mode: "cluster",
        env: {
          ...process.env,
        },
      },
    ],
    deploy: {
      production: {
        user: "harrison",
        host: process.env.HOST,
        key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
        ref: "origin/master",
        repo: process.env.GIT_REPO,
        path: process.env.PROJECT_PATH,
        // Copy keys to server
        "pre-deploy-local": `scp -Cr envs harrison@${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PROJECT_PATH}/current`,
       // Build app and restart PM2 processes
        "post-deploy": `yarn install --ignore-engines && \
           pwd && \
           yarn prod:build && \
           yarn prod:serve`,
      },
    },
  };
```

In order to deploy it to multiple hosts, the PM2 documentation is quite simple: Just add multiple host names. Ok, easy enough. Within my .env file, I'm using a series of IP addresses separated by commas, then splitting those into an array inside my config file, like this:

```
host: process.env.HOST.split(",");
```

However, copying over my .env files to the multiple hosts is not quite so easy.

How can I configure the "pre-deploy-local" portion of this ecosystem file to `scp` my `.env` files to every host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up running a bash script. The list of HOSTS is in my `.env.production` file, separated by commas, like this

`HOSTS=123.12.134.122,134.135.134.134`

To pass them to the Pm2 host, replace each comma with a space and pass them into the bash script as arguments. Then, execute that bash script on the deploy.

My ecosystem file now looks like this:

```
// PM2 CONFIGURATION FOR PRODUCTION BUILDS
require("dotenv").config({ path: `./envs/.production.env` });
const path = require("path");

const hosts = process.env.HOSTS.replace(/,/g, " ");

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: process.env.APP_NAME,
      args: ["--color"],
      interpreter: process.env.NODE_PATH,
      cwd: path.resolve(process.env.PROJECT_PATH, "current"), // Path holding the current version of our app (where post-deploy runs)
      script: "dist/index.js", // Location of
      instances: process.env.INSTANCES || 0,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      env: {
        ...process.env,
      },
    },
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "harrison",
      host: process.env.HOSTS.split(","),
      key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa2",
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: process.env.GIT_REPO,
      // Where to deploy on the server
      path: process.env.PROJECT_PATH,
      // Pass hosts as arguments to .env copy script
      "pre-deploy-local": `./deployEnvs.sh ${
        process.env.PROJECT_PATH
      } ${hosts}`,
      "post-deploy": `yarn install --ignore-engines && \
         yarn prod:build && \
         yarn prod:serve`,
    },
  },
};
```

And the bash script called `deployEnvs.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_PATH="${1}"

for HOST in "${@:2}"
do
    scp -Cr envs "harrison@${HOST}:${PROJECT_PATH}/current"
done
```